# How to make e2ansi-cat work with emacs 26

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors

I'm trying to to cat the file named foo using e2ansi-cat:

```
AdministorsMBP2:~ administrator$ e2ansi-cat --color-class=color --background-mode=light foo
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, face-explorer
AdministorsMBP2:~ administrator$ e2ansi-cat foo
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, face-explorer
```

I added the `--color-class=color --background-mode=light` bit because there was a GitHub issue response that suggested it.

Some additional info:

```
AdministorsMBP2:~ administrator$ /usr/local/bin/emacs --version
GNU Emacs 26.2
AdministorsMBP2:~ administrator$ head -n1 ~/e2ansi/bin/e2ansi-cat 
#!/usr/local/bin/emacs --script
AdministorsMBP2:~ administrator$ head -n1 ~/e2ansi/bin/e2ansi-info 
#!/usr/local/bin/emacs --script
AdministorsMBP2:~ administrator$ which e2ansi-cat
/Users/administrator/e2ansi/bin/e2ansi-cat
```

Comment: The question is unclear, to me.

Comment: I suspect it's not installed correctly and complains about a missing dependency, face-explorer.

Comment: I assume "MBP" is a MacBook Pro ....  If you believe that `face-explorer` is installed and not being seen, then you may have an Emacs `$PATH` issue.  I like to use absolute paths for my executables, but most people who use Macs rely upon a small package to set the path:  https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell